# How to deal with async calls in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, asynchronous

I'm new to node.js and I'm having a hard time trying to understand the concept of event-based async programming.
I'm implementing a restful API web service, so consider the following simple (synchronous!) API  method addStuff(), which inserts stuff to an elasticsearch db:

```
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({ host: 'localhost:9200' });

function indexStuff(stuff) {

    return client.index({
        index: 'test_idx',
        type: 'test',
        id: stuff.id,
        body: stuff
    });
}

function addStuff(req, res, next) {

    let stuff = processRequest(req);

    indexStuff(stuff).then(
        function (body) {
            return true;
        },
        function (error) {
            res.status(error.status).send({ message: error.message });
        }
    );
}
```

So far, so good.
Now during testing I wanted to avoid inserting already existing stuff to the db.
So I'd like to add something like:

```
function stuffAlreadyInDB(id) {
    ... // returns true/false
}

function addStuff(req, res, next) {

    if (stuffAlreadyInDB(req.id))
    {
        res.status(409).send({ message: 'stuff with id ' + req.id + ' already in DB' });
        return;
    }

    var stuff = processRequest(req);

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, the call to the elasticsearch db is asyncronous, which means, I can't just return a boolean in a sync function. Instead, I have to refactor the whole shabang to something (argueably less easy to read) like this:

```
function getStuffByID(id) {

    return client.get({
        id: id,
        index: 'test_idx',
        type: 'test',
        ignore: 404
    });
}

function addStuff(req, res, next) {


    getStuffByID(req.id).then(
        function(resp) {
            if (resp.found) {        
                res.status(409).send({ message: 'stuff with id ' + req.id + ' already in DB' });
                return;
            }
            else {
                var stuff = processRequest(req);
                indexStuff(stuff).then(
                    function (body) {
                        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                        res.end();
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        res.status(error.status).send({ message: error.message });
                    }
                );
            }
        },
        function(error) {

            res.status(error.status).send({ message: error.message });
        }

    );
}
```

At least, I haven't found any better solution. I tried to find out how to make the async call to the db a sync call, but basically everybody was saying: just don't do it.
So how am I supposed to do it right if I don't want to refactor everything and back-factor it when I finished testing and don't need this extra db check anymore?

Oh... and if you downvote my question: leave a comment why you do so.
Because I have the feeling that many people struggle with this issue, but I haven't found a satisfying answer yet.

Comment: async/await would move a little bit of nesting, but... in the end it's not much different. You'd still need a callback to deal with the fact that it's async.

Comment: I don't get your question. You want something which is `async` not to be `async`. Like I want to check a condition but don't want to use `if-else`, `switch` or and other `ternary operator`. I want to loop from 1-100 but not use `for`, `do-while`, `while`, `recursion` or `go-to`. Can you do it? Same is sound of your questions. Things are `async` to make `non-blocking` applications, to handle these `async functions` you can use `callbacks`, `promise`, `async-await` and `generators` to handle `asyns` functions.

Answer (score 1):

you could use async\await syntax to make your code readable. 
for example you could do this:

```
async function getStuffById(){
  //return true or false; }
```

and in the "add stuff" function you could write:

```
if ( await getStuffById() ){
    //do some more stuff }
```

please notice that you have to make "add stuff" async as well in order to use await syntax.

more on async \ await can be found [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

Comment: I am aware of the async/await solution. But what if I don't want to make addStuff() async? This is a web service method and I don't want the client have to deal with async requests.

Comment: you're dealing with code thats async by nature: 'dealing with DB' and the sorts. you could - if you`d prefer 'addStuff' to not be async. to wrap most of the code in an async function outside and then use .then() notation inside your not async addStuff function.